# sql query to search and replace text in all rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to search and replace string in mysql db. I tried to edit it, but editor hangs.

So I need sql query to do same.

How would I do it?

I need to replace instance of dev.domain.com with domain.com

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is:

```
update Table set Column1 = 'domain.com' where Column1 = 'dev.domain.com'
```

In this way, you can do the same without use of replace function!

Comment: Note that **UPDATE** will change the contents of your tables permanently, whereas **REPLACE** changes the result of the query only, leaving the original data intact.

Comment: Assuming that you want to Replace the occurrence of such text in a larger string, the above statement is not sufficient.  This will only change instances where the entire value of the column is 'dev.domain.com'

Answer (score 1):

```
update Table set 
Column1 = replace(Column1, 'dev.domain.com ', 'domain.com')
```

Where Column1 is the column in the Database in which you want to do a replace.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of going with sql statement, I did simple sed from terminal.