# Searching Database column for certain numbers

Tags: php, mysql, admin

I need a query to search a database for a specific number within a group of numbers listed in the same column on a database.

The database `Access` will contain two columns

First column: Page Name

Second Column: Access

And will be set up similar to:   Page Name: Blog-Admin   Access: 60,61,62,76,83,94

where the numbers in the column Access are the ranks that are allowed to view the page.

On each page, there will be a query that finds the users rank and stores it in a $URank variable.

Each page is named in a variable ($PageName) which will match the column Page Name in the `Access` Database

In this query, it needs to search the column Access for the users rank for that page (page name = $PageName)

By storing this in a database, it will allow admins to modify who has access to what pages at any point in time.

I just need the query that will search the database to make sure that user rank has permission to access that page.

This may be very simple, not sure.

I'm use to queries such as  mysql_query("select * from database where blahblah=viarable")...so if it could be answered in this format, that would be fantastic.  Even if its the mysqli equivilant.

Comment: Are ranks arbitrarily assigned to users when they log in? If not, I wouldn't store the user's rank in a session variable; store their user ID (or some abstraction of it), then just look up their rank from your users table.

Comment: User ranks are assigned by admins and stored in our users database.  I have no problem taking user ranks out... in this case I will first search the users database to get the users rank, and then run the query to find out if that users rank is in the access database.  I still need the query for the access database to see if a column contains users rank

Comment: what do you mean by "The database will have two columns"? Is there a _table_ named `Access` with two columns, `Page` and `Access`? Your question still isn't clear.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12903219/sql-query-to-search-and-replace-text-in-all-rows/12948326#12948326

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Okay, it sounds like what you're doing is storing a *string* of allowed ranks in the Access column. **This is a very bad idea**. It's hard to manage and requires a lot of extra work in PHP. What you should do instead is use *two* tables, structured something like this:

```
create table Pages (
    id int primary key auto_increment,
    name varchar(200)
);

create table Page_access (
    page_id int,
    rank int
);
```

So, you'd store a list of all your pages (and nothing else) in the `Pages` table. Then, add to the `Page_access` table all the possible combinations of page IDs (from the `Pages` table) and accepted user ranks for those pages, so `Page_access` might look something like:

```
|page_id | rank |
|   1    |  60  |
|   1    |  61  |
|   1    |  62  |
|   2    |  70  |
|   2    |  71  |
```

... etc. This means you might end up with hundreds of rows in your table—that's okay! It's a normalized table and if you index the columns performance will not be affected.

Alternately, if you know you're always going to accept a rank within a range, you could structure your `Page_access` table like this:

```
create table Page_access (
    page_id int,
    min_rank int,
    max_rant int
);
```

Then just check if the user's rank is between the min and max ranks for the page using SQL's `between`. I hope this helps with organizing your tables, but I know it still doesn't answer your original question (how to write the SQL statements). I'd recommend making sure you've got a good table structure down, then ask another, more specific question once you've tried writing the actual queries.

---

**Original answer:**

Assuming you're using `mysqli`:

```
#connect to your database
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', $database_username, $database_password, 'Access');

#prepare and run the query
if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare('select URank from Access where URank = ?')) {
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $URank);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($exists);
    $stmt->fetch();

    if($exists) {
        #the URank was found in the table
    } else {
        #not found
    }
    $stmt->close();
}
```

Something like that should do the trick. I encourage you to read up on `mysqli` and [prepared statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) before using my example above. You really need to understand what you're doing when writing database queries.

Comment: your PDO link is going to a mysql page =P

Comment: The problem with this is I have no clue how to write code like this.  I have no problem reading it, but modifying it won't be easy.  Is there a way to do this using regular mysql query strings?

Comment: And it doesn't seem like this is searching for the page name?  For each page, different users are allowed access.  So each page will contain my query to see if that URank is allowed access.  The database will contain 2 columns, page name and access.  For each page name, certain ranks have access to it

Comment: That is a regular mysql query string. The `mysql_` functions have been deprecated because they're insecure. They've been replaced by the `mysqli_` set of functions, which when used properly are much more secure. That's why I said you'll want to read up on how to use mysqli and prepared statements before doing ANYTHING with a database.

Comment: Do all mysqli queries use the arrow  ex:  $stmt->bind_param('i', $URank);   Because I never got use to it.  If so, I need to start researching again.

Comment: @kdjernigan: well, now I'm a bit confused. You said 'I want the page to search a database column to see if that users URank is listed in database "Access" Column "Access"' but didn't specify a table name. It would help if you'd edit your question with the structure of the tables you're using so we're on the same page.

Comment: @kdjernigan as for your latest question, no, that's just the object-oriented way of doing it (and the one I happen to prefer since I typically keep my database functions in a class). You can read more about the different ways to use `mysqli_` functions here: http://us1.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php

Comment: My question has be rewritten completely to try to clear up the confusion.  Sorry, its a lot of details and hopefully not confusing this time.  I'm trying my best to get my point across.

Comment: Awesome, thank you!  That will work perfectly.  Never thought about doing it like that.

Comment: No problem. I still suggest reading about the `mysqli_` functions though. They're way more secure and not really any harder to use.